# Tool to test web services

Tags: web-services

I was looking for a tool to test all my webservices whether they are up or down.
Sometimes you run your application and you get exception. Later you find out that the abc or def webservice is down by looking into log files.
So I want to run that tool before hand to know whether all my webservices consumed by my application is up or down.

Answer (score 1):

Better to have an automated tool like Nagios checking whether your hosts, web server, web services, web sites, etc, are up and running, and emailing you when they're not. Also it can check your log files for critical errors and email them to you as well so you don't have to worry until something bad happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), its more complex then [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), and can easy work with [Rest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) services.